# MySQL: how do I map two tables with PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newly responsible for a database.

It contains the tables "users", "role" and "users_roles".

In "users_roles", "uid" (user id) from "users" and "rid" (role id) from "role" are mapped, as the former administrator told me.

WHAT I NEED TO DO: 
I need to create a form by which users can register. Every newly registered user needs to appear in the table "users" of course and at the same time he must be attributed the role "7" and his "uid" must appear together with "rid" = 7 in the table "users_roles".

QUESTION: 
I already know how to add the user to the "users" table. But how do I achieve, that his user id is mapped to the role id = 7 and that this entry appears in the table "users_roles"? Which SQL query do I need to write?    $db->query(' ????????? ')

Comment: What programming language and framework (if any) are you using?

Comment: looks like asp.net membership tables.

Comment: It looks like you're using PHP. All the PHP MySQL APIs have a way to get the auto-increment ID of the last row inserted. Use that when adding the row to `users_role`.

Comment: In PDO it's `$db->lastInsertId()`. In mysqli it's `$db->insert_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding, "But how do I achieve, that his user id is mapped to the role id = 7 and that this entry appears in the table "users_roles"? "

There is always more than one way to do something.  In this case, I would make 7 the default value of the role_id column in the users_roles table.  That would make providing a role_id optional as you add new records.